# Display django user creation form error

Tags: python, django

I'm using django built in user creation form which I extended like this

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'E-mail address'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2')

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        try:
            User._default_manager.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return email
        #raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_email'])
        raise forms.ValidationError('duplicate_email')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if commit:
            user.save()

    return user
```

As you see I've added email validation to check if there is already user with that email (what I don't accept). 
The problem is that neither that of those errors are displaying in my template and I don't know why. I've tried with {{form.field.errors}} and even with {{form.errors.values.[i]}} but nothing helps
I looked in auth.forms to check class UserCreationForm and I see that it pass errors to error_messages but I couldn't find the way to display them.

Although all validations (username check, password check, email check) work fine I'd still like to display error above field with error so that user understands why he couldn't create his account.

UPDATE

**views.py**

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():           
            form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = RegistrationForm()

    return render_to_response('user_profile/register.html', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I hope somebody can help me with that.
Thanks

Comment: Well, at least `email` errors should display if you put it like that: `{{ form.email.errors }}`. Or do you really spell it like `{{ form.field.errors }}`? To be sure.

Comment: No, I write real field name, I put it like that just for example. 
That's what I thought too but unfortunately even email erros doesn't display right and I really don't know why

Comment: Consider showing us your view function.

Comment: I've just updated my question with view function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
def register_user(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        args['form'] = form
        if form.is_valid():           
            form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')
    else:
        args['form'] = RegistrationForm()   

    return render_to_response('user_profile/register.html', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The problem with your code was that you was passing an unbound form instance to your template all the time, so you was just overwriting any occured errors. 
Look here for a reference: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view)

Comment: It works! Thank you very much, now I understand the problem.
I'd like to vote up this answer but unfortunately my reputations is not enough for that so I've just marked it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

If you  are looking at more efficient solution then you should try my below code in views.py file.

Your forms.py code will be same. But it is leakage of validation of password.

```
# to register auth user
class register_user(View):
    template1 = "app_name/register.html" # define templates
    template2 = "app_name/login.html"

    def get(self, request): # get method 
        form = RegistrationForm()
        return render(request, self.template1, locals())

    def post(self, request): # post method
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)     # create form object
        if form.is_valid():
            print "Form is validated"
            user_data = form.save(commit=False)
            user_data.save()
            return render(request, self.template2, locals())
        else:
            print "with error"
            return render(request, self.template1, locals())
```

I hope this will help. I'm still working on good practice of Django.